# ffmpeg makes mov with dropped frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I had 1440 tga files and I wanted to convert them to a 24 fps mov.

Here's the command I used:

```
/usr/local/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -y -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '/Users/ninhenzo64/Documents/Projects/Insta 18/shots/common/images/train/spiral_v023/masterLayer/common_spiral_v023.*.tga' -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 24.0 -s 640x640 '/Users/ninhenzo64/Documents/Projects/Insta 18/shots/common/images/train/spiral_v023/masterLayer/common_spiral_v023.mov'
```

The mov that was generated is 24 fps but it's missing some frames, ffprobe says it's only 57.67s - it should be 60.0s. Also the motion in the file isn't smooth, it's jilty like there are dropped frames.

```
~> ffprobe '/Users/ninhenzo64/Documents/Projects/Insta 18/shots/common/images/train/spiral_v023/masterLayer/common_spiral_v023.mov'
ffprobe version 2.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 19 2014 11:52:35 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 '
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/ninhenzo64/Documents/Projects/Insta 18/shots/common/images/train/spiral_v023/masterLayer/common_spiral_v023.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf55.48.100
  Duration: 00:00:57.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25460 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640, 25459 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 12288 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : DataHandler
      encoder         : Lavc55.69.100 libx264
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Comment: Please show the actual command-line output from the `ffmpeg` command, not `ffprobe`. And please use a more recent version; yours is quite ancient!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1321244/114058